# Failed to create node.js Express with Sass

Tags: node.js, express, webstorm

I'm trying to build my first project of node.js Express server.

I'm using WebStorm IDE witch give me options to select a CSS engine. I try to select Sass and while the initializing the project I'm getting the following error:

[image: Web storm error]

[image: Event log error]

This is only happening when I pick Sass. On every other option (plain CSS, Stylus, Less, Compass) it work's fine.

How can I fix this issue and use Sass (or SCSS) in my project?

My versions:

```
WebStorm: 2017.1.2
npm 5.2.0
node 8.1.4
express 4.15.0
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: According to the error, `npm install` command fails (exit code = 1). Standard output should contain more details. Looks like the screenshot contains only the first few lines of it. Please attach full standard output if the cause is not clear.

Comment: It was the full error I've got, but now I see that if I ignore the error and later check the event log there's more information about the error.. I edited my question with the new error. It looks like the WebStorm is trying to fetch data from github and getting 404 for some reason..

Comment: Thanks, there is more info. However, it's still not the full log. Actually, WebStorm doesn't fetch data from github by itself. It just runs `npm install` which does it. You can run `npm install` in console and there will probably be the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've opened an issue on git and they helped me there..
I needed to update my node-sass package to the latest one (4.5.3). 
Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have sass installed? Because it seems like you need to run

```
npm install node-sass
```

for it to be able to work

Comment: I did tried to install node -sass globally and it didn't helped me. Should I try to ignore the error and install node -sass as project dependency?

Comment: Yeah recently I've not been able to access modules I've saved globally so I'd say navigate to the directory and install it locally there.

Comment: I've installed node-sass but the project still not running. It seems that the issue is in node-sass-middleware witch getting 404 from github